# FIngerprint sensor not showing on asus x507

Tags: fingerprint-reader

**lsusb** is not showing any sign of fingerprint sensor

```
n@thing:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b719 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can i get my finger print sensor work

here is the output from **lshw -short**

```
n@thing:~$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path       Device     Class          Description
====================================================
                          system         X507UA
/0                        bus            X507UA
/0/0                      memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/8                      memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/8/0                    memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
/0/8/1                    memory         [empty]
/0/8/2                    memory         [empty]
/0/8/3                    memory         [empty]
/0/f                      memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/10                     memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/11                     memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/12                     processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
/0/100                    bridge         Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                  display        HD Graphics 520
/0/100/4                  generic        Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                 bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0    usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/6             multimedia     USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
/0/100/14/0/8             communication  Bluetooth Radio
/0/100/14/1    usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2               generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/15                 generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1               generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/16                 communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                 storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1c                 bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c.5               bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
/0/100/1c.5/0  wlp2s0     network        RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
/0/100/1e                 generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0
/0/100/1e.2               generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0
/0/100/1e.6               generic        Sunrise Point-LP Secure Digital IO Controller
/0/100/1f                 bridge         Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2               memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3               multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4               bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/1           scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda   disk           1TB HGST HTS541010B7
/0/1/0.0.0/1              volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2  volume         238GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3   /dev/sda3  volume         476GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/4   /dev/sda4  volume         214GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5   /dev/sda5  volume         1206MiB Linux swap volume
```

Comment: What does `sudo lshw` show about the fingerprint reader? Remember to Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1093886/edit ) your post an insert the appropriate, small, part of `lshw` output. Read `man lshw`.

Comment: updated with lshw -short